# Learn Assembly Language using Raspberry Pi?

Tags: assembly, arm, raspberry-pi

I did a bit of searching but couldn't find a definitive answer on this, so I am hoping I can get your opinion.

I would like to learn Assembly Language (ARM) - would the Raspberry Pi be a good choice for this?

From what I can see it seems there are a few gentle tutorials for doing things like making the LED flash, etc., so from a newbie perspective it isn't too scary, and it actually seems like a lot of fun.

If I started with the Raspberry Pi and then moved onto using disassemblers to build up my knowledge, am I on a good path or am I starting on the wrong foot?

Thank you for your comments.

Comment: Vivek-Ramachandran - [SecurityTube](http://www.securitytube.net/video/208) This just first video...you can find sequential of on security-freak.in

Comment: This site is for specific programming problems you have encountered, not for getting general advice for your education.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Yes and no.  If this is your first assembly language, ARM is a good one (x86 is a bad one) to start with (there are other good ones).  I recommend learning first using an instruction set simulator.  This can give you better visibility into what is going on and will give you a better chance at success (less of a chance of giving up due to frustration).   Once you get your feet wet with the tools, building bare metal programs, etc.  then the raspberry pi is not a bad platform.  the peripherals although poorly documented are very simple to use (compared to other similar platforms) there is enough of a community and examples out there to compensate for the documentation.  the raspberry pi can be considered non-brickable from the ARM's perspective.  Bricking a board trying to make your first blinking led program can be quite frustrating.

I am a big believer in writing a disassembler as a way to learn a new (to me) instruction set.  the ARM instruction set is fixed word length (32 bit) and very easy to disassemble.  the pure thumb instructions are fixed at 16 bit and even easier to disassemble.  thumb has thumb2 extensions though and that makes it harder so I would avoid those at first.  With fixed word length instruction sets you can safely walk through the binary image and disassemble as you go from beginning to end.  data will look strange, but the instructions will be in the right place.  With variable word length you cannot simply start at the beginning and disassemble linearly (using thumb2 extensions means variable-instruction-length)  you might have a three byte instruction, then one byte of data, then another byte of instruction, linearly that byte of data would be disassembled as an instruction and if it happens to decode as a multi-byte instruction then now you are out of sync.  The only proper way to disassemble a variable instruction length binary is to follow all paths of the code in execution order and from that disassemble what you can (without emulating every possible code path you may not be able to distinguish all of the instructions from data).  variable instruction length disassembly is definitely an advanced topic, get some strength in assembly language first.  Perhaps even create an instruction set simulator for a variable word length instruction set before tackling a disassembler (you have to basically, decode your way through the binary anyway, not completely decoding but partially decoding to make a disassembler for a variable word length instruction set.    sorry for the long description there.

both the thumbulator and amber_samples approaches are fixed instruction length making it easy to see the asm to machine code to asm relationship.  as well as see your code running and understand why it went off in to the weeds and died (which you wouldnt see on the raspberry pi or any other hardware).

There is a cambride university example that holds your hand through simple blinking led examples and then into video pixels. as well as other individuals who have posted links to their examples in the bare metal section of the discussion forums.    to get a feel for "how do I do this in assembly language" write small C functions, compile (with optimization) then disassemble.  I am specifically talking about code like a + b, not code like printf().  There is learning the assembly language, the instruciton set, which is specific (common) to the processor family.  then I would argue AFTER THAT learn system calls or library calls.  "how do I print a string" kind of stuff involves either hardware learning, system (a rom monitor/debugger) or library (C library or other higher level languages function calls and convention to take advantage of their libraries, which may themselves call many other libraries causing a lot of junk linked in).  so using C to learn "assembly language" means no library calls, no memcpy no printf etc.  it is up to you though, if you use the system and library calls then you have to write your asm code to run on that system or link with those calls which might themselves have a system dependency.  Think about learning a high level language C or Python, etc.  there is learning the language, declaring variables learning the operators for add, subtract, xor, etc.  How to use pointers and arrays, etc. At some point you learn the C library calls, printf(), strcpy(), malloc, etc.  YMMV, learn then language then the system calls separately or learn the langauge BY learning to interface to the system calls (learn them together).

If you choose to learn asm as part of the system then I recommend staying in linux, create a number simple C functions, compile and disassemble, learn the calling convention for the compiler and use the arm reference materials to look up the instructions as you see them created by the compiler.  learn to create that function from scratch using asm and link it in with the C program, then modify that function.  This is a completely different approach than what I have been describing above.  wrought with the possibility of failure, but is definitely a learn by example approach.